# Bound on difference of measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I am considering the following setting: Let $f,g$ be sufficient 'regular' function, and $A=\{\Delta f<0\}$ and $B=\{\Delta g<0\}$, what I want is that if $||f-g||<\delta$ in some norm, then $\mu(A\Delta B)<\epsilon$(Lebesgue measure),where $A\Delta B$ is the symmetric difference of $A,B$. Can we derive such result with appropriate norm? Any comment and reference shall be appreciated.

Comment: what is the laplace operator applied to a set? ($A\Delta B=$?)

Comment: @Max It's the symmetric difference, sorry for the abuse use of notation. I have editted the post

Comment: ah thanks. you should edit that because it's non standard (i think)

Comment: and do you mean for all epsilon there is a delta such that? (otherwise for each delta and epsilon i know smooth functions which do not fulfill your statement - for example $f=0$ and $\Delta g$ negative, $\left|g\right|_{\infty}$small, and $g$ with huge support)

Comment: @Max You're right. Actually I think at least we can't expect a single infty norm can bound the measure. Maybe it's like the sum of  the norm of all derivatives up to Laplacian....I'm not sure about that

Comment: all you have to do is to claim $\forall\epsilon>0\exists\delta>0$ such that... (your statement) actually i think it's true, but im not sure.

Comment: @Max First I have to find some norm or some criteria of 'closeness' of $f$ and $g$ then I can proceed with that..That's the problem

Comment: the only thing that comes to my mind is this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_in_measure